# I am having a problem with coding this in python

Tags: python

I am trying to solve this problem forever now, I am having a problem when I do a dictionary for the days and for the students I can't store the birthdays since they are dictionaries or maybe I am just lost, how can I write efficient code fr this simple problem

In this simulation question, we will simulate the birthday problem for the case where at least
3 students have the same birthday in a class with 200 students.

For the simulation you can consider this scenario: Assume a bag filled with
numbers from 1 to 365. Then let 200 students pick a ball and then put it back. The
number the students pick is their birthday. Convert this process into a ’function’
in your program, where the return is an array of size with 200 and filled with the
birthdays.

Comment: You can start here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: show some code please

Comment: can you show examples and what have you done?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Remember, always describe your problem in your title, and give code examples, but never links to code, or images of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use python's random module to sample 200 numbers in the range 0-365 without duplicates: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample

Something like:

```
from random import sample

random.sample(range(365), 200)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but I need to put back the number so another student has the probability of choosing the same number, I think in this way a number can be used once which is not what I want.

Comment: In that case you can do `[random.randrange(365) for _ in range(200)]`.

This is a loop that iterates 200 times and each time it adds a number between 0-365 to a list.

The long version would be:

```
    solution = []
    for _ in range(200):
        solution.append(random.randrange(365))
    print(solution)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a dictionary? This may be simpler to do by using a list. By creating a list you can append every birthday drawn (in the case of scenario of the simulation) to the list and have the indices of list correspond to each student. ie. student 1: index 0 would have the birthday: list[index]

Comment: no if you a deferent way I will be glad to hear, I am here to learn